# Processing on TSQL Command

Tags: sql-server, linq, t-sql

I have a Data like this

```
 Id  TagNo   CoreNo     FromLocation    Device    FromTerminal
  1   1000     1           AA             A1         11
  2   1000     2           AA             A1         12
  3   1000     3           AA             A2         13
  4   1000     4           AA             A2         14
  5   1001     1           BB             T1         10
```

I want to have this

```
   TagNo   CoreNo     FromLocation    Device    FromTerminal
    1000     1           AA             A1         11
             2                                     12
             3                          A2         13
             4                                     14
    1001     1           BB             T1         10
```

how can i have it in TSQL / linq?

Answer (score 2):

Formatting the data for display is a job for the application using the data, not the database. There are no specific commands in T-SQL to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, though this is usually handled by a reporting engine (or such).

The following query creates a row number (ROW_NUMBER) per group of duplicate values. Then it only selects the value if it's corresponding row number is 1 by using a CASE.

```
with mt as (
  select 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by tagNo order by Id) as TagRowNr, 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by tagNo,FromLoc order by Id) as FromLocRowNr, 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by tagNo,Device order by Id) as DeviceRowNr, 
    Id, TagNo, Core, FromLoc, Device, FromTerm
  from MyData
)
select 
  Case when TagRowNr=1 then TagNo else '' end as TagNo,
  CoreNo,
  Case when FromLocRowNr=1 then FromLoc else '' end as FromLoc,
  Case when DeviceRowNr=1 then Device else '' end as Device,
  FromTerm
from mt
Order by Id
```